# Add a class to all the blocks in a region

Tags: 7, blocks, theming

I'm theming a Drupal 7 site and I'd like to add a class to all the blocks in a given region using preprocess_block().

I think this should work, but it doesn't seem to:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
        // Other stuff in this function
        $variables['title_attributes_array']['class'][] = 'title';
        $variables['classes_array'][]='clearfix';

        // Now I want to add a 'col-md-4' class to all the blocks in the 'bottom-content' region
        if($variables['block']->region == 'bottom-content') {
                $variables['classes_array'][]='col-md-4';
        }
}
```

Any ideas why this isn't working?

Comment: Are you sure your block region name is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As manikandan kannan is saying, you probably have the name of the region wrong. It probably is: `'content_bottom'`

So your if-statement would become:

```
if($variables['block']->region == 'content_bottom') { ...
```

Comment: The word order was right, but it was an underscore instead of a minus sign. Changing it to 'bottom_content' solved the problem. I should have looked in my MYTHEME.info file sooner - it lists all the regions appropriately.